# Get bulk value from firebase and store in sqlite into android app

Tags: android, firebase

Hi I was trying firebase with , My server has around 300 records which is getting synced with my app in 3 to four minutes in single, single way

cant it be like get record in set of 50 or something ??
If user is coming online after very long time then also I need this batching.

If user is installing app first time then also i need to download bulk record from firebase database

I am using

```
 ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.e(TAG, "addListenerForSingleValueEvent:onDataChange" + dataSnapshot.getValue());

        reference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "addListenerForSingleValueEvent:onCancelled" + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
```

and

```
public class DBService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = DBService.class.getName();
private StartApplication application;
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    application = ((StartApplication) getApplication());
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            try {
                String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                Job job = objectMapper.readValue(json, Job.class);
                ContentValues values = ContentValuesParser.parseJobs(job);
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(TableContract.JobsEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
                Log.d(TAG, "child add id " + job.getId() + " Uri " + uri.getEncodedPath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            //Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(TableContract.JobsEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            try {
                String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                Job job = objectMapper.readValue(json, Job.class);
                ContentValues values = ContentValuesParser.parseJobs(job);
                Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(TableContract.JobsEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
                Log.d(TAG, "child changed id " + job.getId() + " Uri " + uri.getEncodedPath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    reference.child("jobs").addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: you can apply query parameters in your firebase. check this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#data-order

Comment: so i should add datetime parameter to every object and based on that query,  OR firebase automatically add updatedate or created date ??

Comment: When you call `push()` Firebase auto-generates a key that is guaranteed to be unique and always increasing. So you can use `reference.orderByKey().startAt(lastSeenKey)` to only get the new items.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Querying data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)?

```
        Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("weight").limitToLast(50); 
//This will fetch the last 50 children.

queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getKey());
        }
```